# Passing two variables to javascript using make_response in Flask

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Can someone please help me to understand how can I pass two variables from my views to javascript through HTML? 
Everything works fine when I only pass dynamic(takes from db) json-formatted data, but I also need to pass another static integer value all the way to JS file.
When I change view .py file:

```
response = make_response(render_template('live-data.html', data=json.dumps(data)))
```

to

```
response = make_response(render_template('live-data.html', data=json.dumps(data), bpm=777))
```

Then I add {{bpm}} to live-data.html. At last in JS file i change input arguments of the function from

```
success: function(point) {
```

to

```
success: function(point, bpm) {
```

than the stuff which was working before 'breaks'. :/ How can I get both dynamic data tuple and static integer file from my flask views .py in JS file?

This is what I have and **it works fine** before I am making changes to receive 'bpm' value from .py in JS file.

.py file:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/live-data')
def live_data():
    # Create an array and echo it as JSON
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT time, value FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1''')
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    u_time = time.mktime(rv[0]['time'].timetuple())
    value = rv[0]['value']
    #time in unix form
    data = [u_time * 1000, value]
    response = make_response(render_template('live-data.html', data=json.dumps(data)))
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return response
```

**index.html:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="data-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**live-data.html:**

```
{{ data }}
```

and in javascript file:

```
var chart;
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/live-data',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is
                                                 // longer than 20

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

            // title
            // chart.setTitle(null, {text: "Beats per minute - " + bpm});
            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

there is more js code which populates "data-container" on index.html, but i think it's irrelevant here (please let me know if seeing all of it would help).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the approach you're taking now is pretty tedious. You're sending an AJAX request to flask, flask then looks up some data, and the data is then rendered into a text file/html file, the request is then adjusted to be of type json, and only then is returned to the browser.

Flask already has build in functionality to deal with json, so you don't have do all these steps.

Your `success` function in js should only take one argument, the response flask has given you.

```
var chart;
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/live-data',
        success: function(response) {

            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is
                                                 // longer than 20

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(response.data, true, shift);

            // title
            // chart.setTitle(null, {text: "Beats per minute - " + response.bpm});
            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

The response you make using flask can be done using the jsonify function in flask. This function converts a dictionary into a JSON.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/live-data')
def live_data():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT time, value FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1''')
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    u_time = time.mktime(rv[0]['time'].timetuple())
    value = rv[0]['value']
    #time in unix form
    data = [u_time * 1000, value]
    return jsonify({'data': data, 'bpm': 777})
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Joost! It also required me to change "response.point" in JS to "response.data", but the rest about your approach worked great! Appreciate your help!